# Communication error between front end, and back end

Tags: php, jqgrid

For one reason or another, the front end (HTML) of my jqGrid plugin is not communicating properly with the back-end (PHP) of the plugin. I have spent five hours on this now, and I have absolutely nothing to show for it. I have tried both XML as well as jSon methods. i have a feeling I am using an outdated back-end method; however, I cannot be sure as I can't find that great of documentation. I will post my code here as I'm literally falling asleep writing this, and will check back for an update asap (taking a quick nap).

**Front End**

```
<?php 
require_once 'tabs.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery jqGrid Demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.multiselect.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = false;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // first create the grid
        $('#grid').jqGrid({
    url:'grid.php',
    datatype: "json",
    height: 100,
    width: 900,
    colNames:['Customer ID','Hardware ID', 'Username','Password','Email','Last Login','Last IP','Registration Date','Expire Date'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'customerid',index:'customerid', width:150},
        {name:'hardware_id',index:'hardware_id', width:150},
        {name:'username',index:'username', width:100},
        {name:'password',index:'password', width:100},
        {name:'email',index:'email', width:100},
        {name:'lastlogin',index:'lastlogin', width:100},
        {name:'lastipaddress',index:'lastipaddress', width:100},
        {name:'registration_date',index:'registration_date', width:100},
        {name:'expire_date',index:'expire_date', width:100}
    ],
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[5,8,10,20,30], 
    mtype: "GET",
    gridview: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'customerid',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Virtual scrolling on local data"
});

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
        // now you can any time change the width of the grid
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', 900);


    });

//]]>
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div>
          <?php include ("grid.php");?>
      </div>
      <div id="pager"></div>

   </body></html>
```

**Back End - Grid.php**

```
<?php

    include '../dbc.php';
    page_protect();
    require_once 'jq-config.php';
    // include the jqGrid Class
    require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGrid.php";
    // include the driver class
    require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGridPdo.php";
    // Connection to the server

    $link = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    // Tell the db that we use utf-8
    $link ->query("SET NAMES utf8");

    // Create the jqGrid instance
    $grid = new jqGridRender($link);

    $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $grid->SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer_$username";
    // set the ouput format to json
    $grid->dataType = 'json';
    // Let the grid create the model
    $grid->setColModel();
    // Set the url from where we obtain the data
    $grid->setUrl('grid.php');
    // Set some grid options
    $grid->setGridOptions(array("rowNum"=>100,"sortname"=>"customerid","height"=>150));

    // Change some property of the field(s)
    $grid->setColProperty("lastlogin", array(
        "formatter"=>"date",
        "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y"),
        "search"=>false,
        "width"=>"400"
        ));
    // Registration date
    $grid->setColProperty("registration_date", array(
        "formatter"=>"date",
        "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y"),
        "search"=>false,
        "width"=>"400"
        ));
    $grid->setColProperty("expire_date", array(
        "formatter"=>"date",
        "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y"),
        "search"=>false,
        "width"=>"400"
        ));
    $grid->setColProperty("customerid",array("width"=>"650"));
    $grid->setColProperty("hardware_id",array("width"=>"250"));
    $grid->setColProperty("username",array("width"=>"150"));
    $grid->setColProperty("password",array("width"=>"150"));
    $grid->setColProperty("email",array("width"=>"150"));
    $grid->setColProperty("lastipaddress",array("width"=>"100"));

    $grid->setFilterOptions(array("stringResult"=>true));
    $grid->navigator=true;
    $grid->setNavOptions('navigator',array("excel"=>true,"add"=>true,"edit"=>true,"view"=>true,"del"=>true,"search"=>true));
    // Enjoy
    $grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
    $link = null;
    ?>
```

Comment: I added the tag [jqgrid-php](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-php/info) to the list of tags of your question. (Compare with the description of [jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info) tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use myself any commercial version of jqGrid like jqSuite or jqGrid for PHP, but after the first look at [the demo page](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx) I could see some problems in your code:

Your code is a mix from the jqGrid and the code of the commercial version of jqGrid.

If you use jqGrid for PHP you should **remove** the code in `$(document).ready(function() {/*the code should be removed*/`. Because you use the line

```
$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
```

in your PHP code you should the body of your HTML code to

```
<div> 
    <?php include ("grid.php");?> 
</div>
```

In the case the HTML fragment `<table id="grid"></table><div id="page"></div>` will produces the PHP code you you.

If you don't use the commercial version of jqGrid you should include `<table id="grid"></table>` in your HTML code. You should also change `'#pager2'` parameter of `'navGrid'` to `'#pager'`. To have the grid filled with the data you need change `url` parameter of jqGrid to any URL which provide JSON data for the grid. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) about the format of the JSON data.

Comment: The #1 issue I'm having is when I use your tips from my last question, the SIZE works perfectly and the data doesn't show up. When I use your tips here, the data shows up and the size won't go to what I want it to.

Comment: @Evan: Sorry, but I absolutely not understand your comment. What you mean under "SIZE"? What you mean under "last question": this question or the previous one?  What exactly work and what not work in your code?

Comment: By 'size' I am referring to the width of the grid, it's staying at an ugly fixed width of around 35% of the page it's being displayed on. Furthermore, the column names are being displayed as the actual column name in my database, as opposed to the custom names that I had given them. By 'last question' i was referring to my previous one. Currently, my grid is being filled with the proper data from my database but I can not appropriately change the width of the grid itself which is annoying me.

Comment: @Evan: Do you use now commercial or free version of jqGrid? In case of commercial version do you set any value for the `width` jqGrid option in the call of `setGridOptions` method? Why you use the values like `"width"=>"400"` or `"width"=>"650"` if you want to have `width: 900` for the whole grid?

Comment: Everything is good now, got it working (thanks to you no doubt).

Comment: @Evan: The grid width depend on many other parameters which you can use. If you set for example the jqGrid width to `width: 900` and the width of 8 column to 200 the actual width of every column will be 100 because of `shrinkToFit: true` which is default. If you set explicitly `shrinkToFit: false` in the `setGridOptions` method you should have grid horizontal scroll bar in the grid and the size of all columns will stay unchanged (200).

Comment: you went above and beyond here, thank you very much. I am more than 100% satisfied with this answer.